# Is multicollinearity a problem when fitting a Bayesian regression model using ADVI?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multicollinearity, variational-bayes, pymc3

If I’m fitting a bayesian regression model using ADVI, is it important to ensure all the covariates are uncorrelated with each other? I have a vague understanding that ADVI doesn’t play well with correlations in the posterior, and my understanding is that multicollinearity should produce correlation between the posterior estimates of the coefficients.
(This question is a duplicate of [this question][1] on the PyMC3 discourse forum

[1]: https://discourse.pymc.io/t/is-multicollinearity-a-problem-when-fitting-a-regression-model-using-advi/8495)

Comment: with the default spherical advi it would be a problem, could you use the elliptical (which requires many more paramters, so slower...)

Comment: Speed is pretty important for my application so I'd prefer to stick with the default unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get from ADVI - credible intervals?  If that's the case I think you will need elliptical.  But just test it on a few cases and compare the results.in my experience, the point estimates were accurate with ADVI spherical ( I compared to NUTS) the prediction intervals were not.

Comment: Ideally I would like accurate credible intervals as well as point estimates. Is there a reasonable way for me to transform my covariates so that they are uncorrelated with each other, ideally in a way that preserves some interpretability (not PCA)? I was wondering about recursively regressing the predictors against each other and using the residuals (eg regress predictor 2 against pred 1, use residual, regress predictor 3 against  residual 1, and so on)

Comment: have you tested the speed with elliptic parametrisation?  You can do a QR factorisation (including subtracting mean from each variable). https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_28/stan-users-guide/QR-reparameterization.html.  However, your priors are then on these rotated dimensions.

Comment: I haven't tested elliptic parameterization because I'm not sure how to do it (working in PyMC3). Thanks for the suggestion on QR factorization, that was basically what I was looking for.

Comment: In pymc3 you should use https://pymc3-testing.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-docs/api/inference.html#pymc3.variational.inference.FullRankADVI ... But don't know details